# Unable to connect to mongo atlas using Kubernetes service

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, mongodb-atlas

I could able to connect to mongodb atlas with uri: mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.q2w3e.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Now, I want to connect through extername service.

Here is my service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-atlas
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: "cluster0.p9jq2.mongodb.net"
```

```
And I changed spring.data.mongodb.uri to mongodb+srv://username:password@mongo-atlas/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

But Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Is `cluster0.p9jq2.mongodb.net` a valid CNAME, what's the output for `nslookup cluster0.p9jq2.mongodb.net`?

Comment: `mongodb+srv` will be doing a DNS lookup for an SRV record of `_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.p9jq2.mongodb.net`, and then a TXT record for `cluster0.p9jq2.mongodb.net`.  I don't know if either can be redirected with a CNAME.

Comment: @Joe then how should I give this?

Comment: It may be easier to use the `mongodb://` kind of connection string, so the hostnames are resolved as `A` records.  I don't know how to get k8s to resolve SRV

Answer (score 0):

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found`

This is actually correct since TXT record is resolvable but is **not reachable**. It is meant for the driver to perform host discovery. This way allows backend change without require you to change your connection string.

Typically, the connection string can be saved in a ConfigMap and mount to your pod as config file. You don't need an ExternalService to perform CNAME lookup in this case.